# Is there any way to use leaflet to zoom into a rectangular image?

Tags: zooming, leaflet

I use leaflet to zoom into images in webapps that I've made (see http://rihannadecoded.com for an example site). In order to make the images work, I need to make sure that they are a square that can break down into 256x256 pixel chunks.

Now I'd like to create a similar site for an image that is  5000x2000 pixels (or whatever other non-square resolution). Is there any way that I can use leaflet to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter if the image is square and could be splitted ub to 256x256 chunks.

For a 5000x2000 image you e.g. may use 250x250 - tiles(use the tileSize-option to define the size of the tiles).

When the image can't be splitted into square chunks, you still have the option to complete the partially tiles on right/bottom with a background-color of your choice.

Comment: ok so then it seems that the challenge is just splitting the images into the appropriate tiles. I used gdal2tiles.py (http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) for my original square images (that are multiples of 256x256), but I guess I'll need to create my own scripts using the python imaging library for rectangular images. Do you know of any easier method by any chance before I get started on that?

Comment: :D you got enough periods in there to get past the character limit!! :D

Comment: there wasn't more to say for me than "nö", sorry :D

Comment: haha absolutely no need to be sorry. i've been in the same boat before :)